# Mongo Security Authentication Not Working

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get MongoDB authentication working on my AWS Linux server.  I have run authentication using MongoDB running on windows with no issues,

```
>mongod --auth
```

On my AWS server I am trying to run MongoDB using the service command,

```
$ sudo service mongod start
```

However, mogod does not start.  I believe the problem is with my /etc/mongod.conf file.  Here is the /etc/mongod.conf with authentication enabled,

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
destination: file
logAppend: true
path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
journal:
enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on    all interfaces.

security:
authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

The problem is with the security tag.

```
security:
authorization: enabled
```

If I include it, MongoDB will not start.  If I take it out, MongoDB starts fine but has no security.  What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my bad...The file is of type YAML.  I originally entered,

```
security:
authorization: enabled
```

Because it's YAML, I needed a couple of spaces.  The correct entry is,

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Works fine now.

By the way, If you are using MongoDB and have a public IP/port exposed I would highly recommend that you enable security.  I got an email last week from AWS saying that if you are using MongoDB that has a port that is publicly available you should implement security.  I am still in development so I ignored the AWS recommendation.  Well, 3 days later, someone accessed my databases, copied them, deleted them, and left me a ransomware note in a new database.  They wanted one bitcoin for the return of my existing databases.  I did not pay the ransom.  Fortunately, this was not a problem for me.  All of the data was limited test data. To avoid potential malware bombs, I deleted the AWS instance, created a new instance and installed a fresh MongoDB release with authorization enabled.

This episode could have been a disaster with real customer data.  If you are using MongoDB with public access make sure you enable authorization.